# Count number of weeks, days and months from a certain date in PySpark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, date, pyspark

So, I have a DataFrame of this type:

```
+-------------------+
|               date|
+-------------------+
|2020-05-10 22:40:51|
|2020-05-10 23:05:25|
|2020-05-10 22:49:42|
|2020-05-10 23:16:06|
|2020-05-10 22:33:25|
+-------------------+
```

And I want to create multiple columns containing, for each line, the current day, week, month and year from a certain date(simply a year, like 2020 for 2020-01-01). At first I thought of using something like this line of code

```
dataframe = df.withColumn('year', F.year('date')-initial_date).withColumn('month', F.month('date')+col(year)*12).withColumn('week', F.weekofyear('date')++col(year)*52).withColumn('day', F.dayofyear('date')+col(year)*365)
```

unfortunately this wouldn't work (except for year and month) correctly since my dataset spans through several years and some of them have more weeks (53,52) and more days (365,366). I know I could quite surely do something like that with an UDF but I want to use it only as a last resort since my dataset will be quite big and I'd love not to sacrifice performances.

Comment: Please define what *you* mean by "week".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the day difference, you can use `datediff`, and from that, you can get the week difference by dividing the number of days by 7, and rounding down to integer:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

initial_date = 2020

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'year', 
    F.year('date')-initial_date
).withColumn(
    'month', 
    F.month('date')+F.col('year')*12
    # or you can use 
    # F.months_between('date', F.lit('%s-01-01'%initial_date)).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'day', 
    F.datediff('date', F.lit('%s-01-01'%initial_date))
).withColumn(
    'week', 
    (F.col('day') / 7).cast('int')
)

df2.show()
+-------------------+----+-----+---+----+
|               date|year|month|day|week|
+-------------------+----+-----+---+----+
|2020-05-10 22:40:51|   0|    5|130|  18|
|2020-05-10 23:05:25|   0|    5|130|  18|
|2020-05-10 22:49:42|   0|    5|130|  18|
|2020-05-10 23:16:06|   0|    5|130|  18|
|2020-05-10 22:33:25|   0|    5|130|  18|
+-------------------+----+-----+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

SparkSQL has the following functions built-in:  `year()`, `month()`, and `weekofyear()`.  These seem to do what you want:

```
select year(date), month(date), weekofyear(date)
from dataframe;
```

I don't know what you mean by "day".  You presumably want either `dayofmonth()` or `dayofyear()`.